# Choose and evaluate a function from a list in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

Using C++, I need to choose a function from a list and then evaluate that function with some inputs. I know just enough to be dangerous, I've solved my problem through some magic, but I have questions regarding my solution. Here is a minimal working example:

```
double foo(double x) {return x+2;}
double bar(double x) {return x*7;}
double baz(double x) {return x-1;}

int main() {

  double x = 3;
  auto func_list = {foo,bar,baz};

  // This is chosen from an external source, 
  // setting to a fixed value for the example 
  int random_choice = 1;

  double y = (*(func_list.begin()+random_choice))(x);

  return 0;
}
```

**Question:** Is this the right way to chose a function from a list and evaluate it?  `auto` here was a double-edged sword, it created *something*, but I don't know what type it is.

Comment: By the way: you don't need to dereference a pointer-to-function, so you could simplify that to: `double y = func_list.begin()[random_choice](x);` Also: http://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with,

```
auto func_list = {foo,bar,baz};
```

creates a variable of type `std::initializer_list<double (*)(double)>`. While what you have works, it might be better to use a more expected container:

```
std::vector<double(*)(double)> func_list = {foo, bar, baz};
```

Either way, you can write a `random_select` function like:

```
template <typenme Iter>
auto random_select(Iter begin, Iter end) -> decltype(*begin)
{
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, std::distance(begin, end) - 1);
    return *std::next(begin, dis(gen));
}

template <typename C>
auto random_select(const C& cont) -> decltype(*cont.begin()) {
    return random_select(cont.begin(), cont.end());
}

double y = random_select(func_list)(x);
```

Comment: The unfortunate part about `static` random number generators is that they provide shared, mutable state across threads. So better not call `random_select` from multiple threads concurrently.

Comment: Thanks for the implementation! I'm a little confused on what is happening with the line `auto random_select(Iter begin, Iter end) -> decltype(*begin)`, what does `-> decltype(*begin)` do after the return type and normal function header?

Comment: @Hooked it's called trailing return type. In short, I want to return an object of type `decltype(*begin)`, but `begin` as a name doesn't exist yet in the normal return type spot - so I can't write `decltype(*begin) random_select(Iter begin, Iter end)`. But I can refer to it later. If you google for C++11 trailing return type, you can find some more complete descriptions.

Answer (score 3):

> [auto] created something, but I don't know what type it is.

When assigning a braced list (of the same type) to an `auto`, such as:

```
auto func_list = {foo,bar,baz};
```

the list will always convert to a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).  That is the type of your auto variable.

> Is this the right way?

From there, your remaining code is valid.  Whether it's *the right way* will always be up to you.

Comment: Thanks! Now that I know what they are called I can read up on them. Is there an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: I haven't used `std::initializer_list` much, but I'm inclined to think it should only really be used as a mechanism for list-initialisation (with maybe some exceptions).

Comment: @Hooked you may use any sort of container object, and gain the benefits of that container type.  If your functions are numerically indexed, an array or `vector` would also work.  If you wanted to index the functions with something non-numeric, you may consider a `map`.

Comment: @DrewDormann I'm drawing my functions from `std::discrete_distribution<int>` which are the weights I'd like to sample each function (this gives me my `random_choice`).

Answer (score 1):

You said,

> `auto` here was a double-edged sword, it created something, but I don't know what type it is.

You can create an array of function pointers and use the array, if that makes it simpler for you. Like:

```
double foo(double x) {return x+2;}
double bar(double x) {return x*7;}
double baz(double x) {return x-1;}

int main() {

   double x = 3;

   // Use the compiler to get a type that can be used to define an array.
   typedef decltype((&foo)) function_type;

   // Define an array of function pointers.
   function_type func_list[] = {foo, bar, baz};

   // Now use the array to call one of the functions.    
   int random_choice = 1;
   double y = func_list[random_choice](x);

   return 0;
}
```

If you don't wish to use compiler magic, you can use:

```
int main() {

   double x = 3;

   // Define a function type using typedef
   typedef double (*function_type)(double);

   // Define an array of function pointers.
   function_type func_list[] = {foo, bar, baz};

   // Now use the array to call one of the functions.    
   int random_choice = 1;
   double y = func_list[random_choice](x);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a neat trick, `typedef decltype(...)`. I hadn't thought of using it that way! It's still compile time magic, but it is one layer removed.